# Disabling link when setting position of elements

Tags: html, css, angularjs

It sometimes happens to me that when I set position of some element (top: , right: and ...) some of my links will disable and when I put my mouse on it, The hand sign doesn't appear. I want to know why It happens and how can I improve that.
This is my page: [Google link is disabled.]

Can anyone explain my error and solve the problem?
My CSS Code:

```
#second_imglist {
            position: relative;
            right: -100px;
        }

        #squares {
            position: absolute;
            top: 630px;
            right: 400px;
        }

        #imgset {
            position: relative;
            top: 30px;
        }
```

Some HTML codes I think they create the problem:

```
           <div class="w3-half">

                <div data-ng-include="'variables/logo1.html'"></div>
                <div class="w3-row w3-margin-top" id="imgset">
                    <div data-ng-include src="file"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-half w3-center" id="img_controllers">
                <div data-ng-include src="includehtml"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-center" id="squares">
        <a href="#" data-ng-click="nextslide(2)">Google</a>
        <i class="fa fa-square" data-ng-click="nextslide(1)"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-square-o" data-ng-click=""></i>
        </div>
```

Comment: @PeeHaa , I improved my question...

Comment: There's no PHP here and it looks like you're using Angular JS. Please fix your question.

Answer (score 0):

the `i` tags not inside of the `a` tag, so that's why hand cursor is not appearing...

and u can try adding `cursor: pointer;`to your i tags in css

Answer (score 0):

```
i {
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

should work.

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.